# Select the next greatest value from a column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm using SQL server and I have a table that looks like this (Table1). I want to look ahead to the next greatest `AccountId` value in the table by running a select statement.

Table1

| CompanyId | AccountId | CustomerId |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 14 | 2 |
| 1 | 14 | 5 |
| 1 | 17 | 3 |
| 1 | 18 | 1 |
| 1 | 18 | 2 |
| 2 | 7 | 3 |
| 2 | 7 | 4 |
| 2 | 25 | 1 |

I've tried using lead() but that's not doing what I want. It's only looking ahead to the next 'AccountId', not the next greatest. I only want to look ahead for the same 'CompanyId' and every time the 'AccountId' changes.

```
Select lead(AccountId, 1) over (partition by CompanyId order by CompanyId, CustomerId) as NextAccountId
From Table1
```

This is my desired outcome

| CompanyId | AccountId | CustomerId | NextAccountId |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 14 | 2 | 17 |
| 1 | 14 | 5 | 17 |
| 1 | 17 | 3 | 18 |
| 1 | 18 | 1 | NULL |
| 1 | 18 | 2 | NULL |
| 2 | 7 | 3 | 25 |
| 2 | 7 | 4 | 25 |
| 2 | 25 | 1 | NULL |

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done with a simple correlated sub-query:

```
select *, (
  select Min(t2.accountId) 
  from t t2 
  where t2.CompanyId=t.CompanyId and t2.accountId > t.accountId 
) as NextAccountId
from t;
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do this entirely with window functions, and **only scanning the base table once**.

```sql
SELECT *,
  NextAccount = MAX(NextRow) OVER (PARTITION BY CompanyId, AccountId)
FROM (
    SELECT *,
      NextRow = NULLIF(LEAD(AccountId) OVER (PARTITION BY CompanyId ORDER BY AccountId), AccountId)
    FROM Table1
) t
```

We use `LEAD` sorted by `AccountId` to get the next row's value. We null it out if it equals the current row.

Then `MAX` or `MIN` of that, while partitioning (not sorting) by `AccountId`, gets us the only non-null value in the partition.

[**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=186f9cf750854e16e52a3ad340c5a970)